# Should I download a data panel/chart from the web by Python?

Tags: python, charts, download

for example, in this website: "https://www.lookintobitcoin.com/charts/1-year-hodl-wave/"
I want to download the data in the chart, and if I can't, I want to save the fig on local;
Should I do this?

using Dash Winterson's code, I get part of the fig as below:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this in python via Selenium

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep

url = "https://www.lookintobitcoin.com/charts/1-year-hodl-wave/"

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)

driver.get_screenshot_as_file("webpage_with_graph.png")
driver.quit()
```

after which you could use something like Pillow/PIL to slice the image down to just the graph if you need

Comment: hi Dash Winterson, thanks a lot;
I have tried and get a fig by your code; but the fig is just a part not whole fig.

Comment: is the webpage maybe cut off? you can probably modify the window size via the `driver` var